# Limit with trigonometric function $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan^2(x)-1}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have this limit, I have resolved it until a part but I'm stucked now.

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan^2(x)-1}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}-\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\frac{\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}{\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{1}}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{ \sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)(\cos(x)-\sin(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin(x)-\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}-\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}-\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$

And now I replace by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and what I get is $0$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{ \sin^2 x-\cos^2 x}{\cos x -\sin x} \neq \sin x-\cos x .$$

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't know what I was doing

Comment: @Manuel This is an error prone business. The mark of skill here lies in a developed ability to consistently recover from the inevitable errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

Going from line 4 to line 5, $(\sin^2x-\cos^2x)/(\cos x-\sin x)=-\sin x-\cos x$